# No redirecciona a index.php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una web en PHP con un login que una vez apretado el boton de login no me redirecciona al index si no que se queda dentro de login. Adjunto los codigos para **index**, **login**, **registration_login**

**index.php**

```
<?php require_once('config.php') ?>
<?php require_once('public_functions.php') ?>

<?php $posts = getPost(); ?>

<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $_SESSION['msg'] = 'You must log in first';
  header('location: login.php');
}

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  session_destroy();
  unset($_SESSION['username']);
  header('location: login.php');
}

?>

<a href="register.php">Register</a>

<h1>Hello</h1>

<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
  <span><?php echo $post['id'] ?></span>
  <h2><?php echo $post['title'] ?></h2>
  <p><?php echo $post['body'] ?></p>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

**login.php**

```
    <?php include('config.php') ?>
<?php include('registration_login.php') ?>

<h1>Login Form</h1>


<form method="post" action="login.php">
  <?php include('errors.php') ?>

  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username">

  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password">

  <button type="submit" name="login_user">Login</button>

  <p>
    Not yet a member? <a href="register.php">Sign up</a>
  </p>

</form>
```

**registration_login.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

//inicializo variables, almacenaran datos
$username = "";
$email = "";
$password_1 = "";
$errors = array();

//conecto a la db
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

//registro de usuarios
if(isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
   //recibe todos los input values del form y los guarda en las variables declaradas
   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
   $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
   $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password_1']);
   $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password_2']);

   //validacion del form: "SE ASEGURA QUE LA FORMA ESTE BIEN LLENADA"
   // por cada verificacion en caso de ser negativa se iran agregando los errores al final del array dentro de la variable errors.php!!!!!!!
   if(empty($username)) {
       array_push($errors, 'username is required');
   }
   if(empty($email)) {
       array_push($errors, 'email is required');
   }

   if(empty($password_1)) {
       array_push($errors, 'password is required');
   }

   if($password_1 != $password_2) {
       array_push($errors, 'passwords do not match, please check');
   }
}

//antes de enviar chequear con una consulta a la db que el usuario o email ingresado no exista

//creo una variable que guarde la informacion de la consulta
$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $user_check_query);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

//advertencia mediantes sentencias if para la variable user
if($user) {
    //toma de los valores de la variable user el username en la bd
    if($user['username'] === $username) {
        array_push($errors, 'username already exists');
    }

    if($user['email'] === $email) {
        array_push($errors, 'email already exists');
    }
}

//si no hay ningun error, registra el usuario en la db insertando los datos guardados en las variables

//si los errores en la form == 0
if(count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1); //encripta la password antes de guardarla en la bd

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
              VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    //variables superglobales de session, almacena datos del usuario para las sesiones
    $_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'you are logged in';
    //redirecciona
    header('location: index.php');
}

// Login user

//login de usuario
if(isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    //recibe los datos del form y los los guarda 
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

    //validacion del form
    if(empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Username is required');
    }

    if(empty($password)){
        array_push($errors, 'Password is required');
    }

    //Si no hay errores, consulta en la bd y devuelve el valor con la informacion de log consultada
    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = 'You are logged in';
            header('location: index.php');
        } else {
            array_push($errors, 'Wrong username/password');
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cambiar el `action` de tu formulario para que apunte a `index.php` asi:

```
<?php include('config.php') ?>
<?php include('registration_login.php') ?>

<h1>Login Form</h1>


<form method="post" action="index.php">
  <?php include('errors.php') ?>

  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username">

  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password">

  <button type="submit" name="login_user">Login</button>

  <p>
    Not yet a member? <a href="register.php">Sign up</a>
  </p>

</form>
```

Comment: vale @alanfcm pero aun persiste de hecho desde las rutas que sea /index.php para el root path me muestra de entrada el login quizas me falte el boton de logout y cerrar la sesion pero aun asi deberia redireccionarme